# FDT Milestone 8 (1.14.321.1744) web project can't find playerglobal.swc mx.swc libraries

Tags: eclipse, fdt

I just installed FDT Milestone 8 (1.14.321.1744) from http://fdt.powerflasher.com/update/fdt5 on Eclipse Kepler 4.3.2 on Fedora.  Any time I start a new Web project, the libraries playerglobal.swc and mx.swc cannot be found by FDT.  If I go to the:

- Project > Properties
- FDT Build Path (on right)
- SDK Library

both playerglobal.swc and mx.swc show errors.

The path for playerglobal is 
`frameworks/libs/player//playerglobal.swc`
but this is wrong, it should be
`frameworks/libs/player/11.1/playerglobal.swc`

the path for mx.swc is
`frameworks/libs/mx/mx.swc`
This seems to be the correct path, but it still has an error.

My flex config file is provided below.  Is there any work around for this?

Thanks!

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<!--

    ADOBE SYSTEMS INCORPORATED
    Copyright 2005-2007 Adobe Systems Incorporated
    All Rights Reserved.

    NOTICE: Adobe permits you to use, modify, and distribute this file
    in accordance with the terms of the license agreement accompanying it.

-->

<flex-config>
    <!-- Specifies the minimum player version that will run the compiled SWF. -->
   <target-player>11.1</target-player>

    <!-- Specifies the version of the compiled SWF -->
    <swf-version>14</swf-version>

   <compiler>

      <!-- Turn on generation of accessible SWFs. -->
      <accessible>true</accessible>

      <!-- Specifies the locales for internationalization. -->
      <locale>
          <locale-element>en_US</locale-element>
      </locale>

      <!-- List of path elements that form the roots of ActionScript class hierarchies. -->
      <!-- not set -->
      <!--
      <source-path>
         <path-element>string</path-element>
      </source-path>
      -->

     <!-- Allow the source-path to have path-elements which contain other path-elements -->
     <allow-source-path-overlap>false</allow-source-path-overlap>

      <!-- Run the AS3 compiler in a mode that detects legal but potentially incorrect -->
      <!-- code.                                                                       -->
      <show-actionscript-warnings>true</show-actionscript-warnings>

      <!-- Turn on generation of debuggable SWFs. False by default for mxmlc, -->
      <!-- but true by default for compc. -->
      <!--
      <debug>true</debug>
      -->

      <!-- List of SWC files or directories to compile against but to omit from -->
      <!-- linking.                                                             -->
      <external-library-path>
          <path-element>libs/player/{targetPlayerMajorVersion}.{targetPlayerMinorVersion}/playerglobal.swc</path-element>
      </external-library-path>

      <!-- Turn on writing of generated/*.as files to disk. These files are generated by -->
      <!-- the compiler during mxml translation and are helpful with understanding and   -->
      <!-- debugging Flex applications.                                                  -->
      <keep-generated-actionscript>false</keep-generated-actionscript>

      <!-- not set -->
      <!--
      <include-libraries>
         <library>string</library>
      </include-libraries>
      -->

      <!-- List of SWC files or directories that contain SWC files. -->
      <library-path>
         <path-element>libs</path-element>
         <path-element>libs/mx</path-element>
         <path-element>locale/{locale}</path-element>
         <!-- The following entry is because LCDS copies playerfds.swc in the player folder -->
         <path-element>libs/player</path-element>
      </library-path>

      <namespaces>
      <!-- Specify a URI to associate with a manifest of components for use as MXML -->
      <!-- elements.                                                                -->
         <namespace>
            <uri>http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009</uri>
            <manifest>mxml-2009-manifest.xml</manifest>
         </namespace>
         <namespace>
            <uri>library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark</uri>
            <manifest>spark-manifest.xml</manifest>
         </namespace>
         <namespace>
            <uri>library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx</uri>
            <manifest>mx-manifest.xml</manifest>
         </namespace>
         <namespace>
            <uri>http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml</uri>
            <manifest>mxml-manifest.xml</manifest>
         </namespace>
      </namespaces>

      <!-- Enable post-link SWF optimization. -->
      <optimize>true</optimize>

      <!-- Enable trace statement omission. -->
      <omit-trace-statements>true</omit-trace-statements>

      <!-- Keep the following AS3 metadata in the bytecodes.                                             -->
      <!-- Warning: For the data binding feature in the Flex framework to work properly,                 -->
      <!--          the following metadata must be kept:                                                 -->
      <!--          1. Bindable                                                                          -->
      <!--          2. Managed                                                                           -->
      <!--          3. ChangeEvent                                                                       -->
      <!--          4. NonCommittingChangeEvent                                                          -->
      <!--          5. Transient                                                                         -->
      <!--
      <keep-as3-metadata>
          <name>Bindable</name>
          <name>Managed</name>
          <name>ChangeEvent</name>
          <name>NonCommittingChangeEvent</name>
          <name>Transient</name>
      </keep-as3-metadata>
      -->

      <!-- Turn on reporting of data binding warnings. For example: Warning: Data binding -->
      <!-- will not be able to detect assignments to "foo".                               -->
      <show-binding-warnings>true</show-binding-warnings>

      <!-- toggle whether warnings generated from unused type selectors are displayed -->
      <show-unused-type-selector-warnings>true</show-unused-type-selector-warnings>

      <!-- Run the AS3 compiler in strict error checking mode. -->
      <strict>true</strict>

      <!-- Use the ActionScript 3 class based object model for greater performance and better error reporting. -->
      <!-- In the class based object model most built-in functions are implemented as fixed methods of classes -->
      <!-- (-strict is recommended, but not required, for earlier errors) -->
      <as3>true</as3>

      <!-- Use the ECMAScript edition 3 prototype based object model to allow dynamic overriding of prototype -->
      <!-- properties. In the prototype based object model built-in functions are implemented as dynamic      -->
      <!-- properties of prototype objects (-strict is allowed, but may result in compiler errors for         -->
      <!-- references to dynamic properties) -->
      <es>false</es>

      <!-- List of CSS or SWC files to apply as a theme. -->
      <theme>
         <!-- The Flex 4 default theme is Spark. -->
         <filename>themes/Spark/spark.css</filename>
      </theme>

      <!-- Turns on the display of stack traces for uncaught runtime errors. -->
      <verbose-stacktraces>false</verbose-stacktraces>

      <!-- Defines the AS3 file encoding. -->
      <!-- not set -->
      <!--
      <actionscript-file-encoding></actionscript-file-encoding>
      -->

      <fonts>

          <!-- Enables advanced anti-aliasing for embedded fonts, which provides greater clarity for small -->
          <!-- fonts. This setting can be overriden in CSS for specific fonts. -->
          <!-- NOTE: flash-type has been deprecated. Please use advanced-anti-aliasing <flash-type>true</flash-type> -->
          <advanced-anti-aliasing>true</advanced-anti-aliasing>

          <!-- The number of embedded font faces that are cached. -->
          <max-cached-fonts>20</max-cached-fonts>

          <!-- The number of character glyph outlines to cache for each font face. -->
          <max-glyphs-per-face>1000</max-glyphs-per-face>

          <!-- Defines ranges that can be used across multiple font-face declarations. -->
          <!-- See flash-unicode-table.xml for more examples. -->
          <!-- not set -->
          <!--
          <languages>
              <language-range>
                  <lang>englishRange</lang>
                  <range>U+0020-007E</range>
              </language-range>
          </languages>
          -->

          <!-- Compiler font manager classes, in policy resolution order-->
          <managers>
              <manager-class>flash.fonts.JREFontManager</manager-class>
              <manager-class>flash.fonts.BatikFontManager</manager-class>
              <manager-class>flash.fonts.AFEFontManager</manager-class>
              <manager-class>flash.fonts.CFFFontManager</manager-class>
          </managers>

          <!-- File containing cached system font licensing information produced via
               java -cp mxmlc.jar flex2.tools.FontSnapshot (fontpath)
               Will default to winFonts.ser on Windows XP and
               macFonts.ser on Mac OS X, so is commented out by default.

          <local-fonts-snapshot>localFonts.ser</local-fonts-snapshot>
          -->

      </fonts>

      <!-- Array.toString() format has changed. -->
      <warn-array-tostring-changes>false</warn-array-tostring-changes>

      <!-- Assignment within conditional. -->
      <warn-assignment-within-conditional>true</warn-assignment-within-conditional>

      <!-- Possibly invalid Array cast operation. -->
      <warn-bad-array-cast>true</warn-bad-array-cast>

      <!-- Non-Boolean value used where a Boolean value was expected. -->
      <warn-bad-bool-assignment>true</warn-bad-bool-assignment>

      <!-- Invalid Date cast operation. -->
      <warn-bad-date-cast>true</warn-bad-date-cast>

      <!-- Unknown method. -->
      <warn-bad-es3-type-method>true</warn-bad-es3-type-method>

      <!-- Unknown property. -->
      <warn-bad-es3-type-prop>true</warn-bad-es3-type-prop>

      <!-- Illogical comparison with NaN. Any comparison operation involving NaN will evaluate to false because NaN != NaN. -->
      <warn-bad-nan-comparison>true</warn-bad-nan-comparison>

      <!-- Impossible assignment to null. -->
      <warn-bad-null-assignment>true</warn-bad-null-assignment>

      <!-- Illogical comparison with null. -->
      <warn-bad-null-comparison>true</warn-bad-null-comparison>

      <!-- Illogical comparison with undefined. Only untyped variables (or variables of type *) can be undefined. -->
      <warn-bad-undefined-comparison>true</warn-bad-undefined-comparison>

      <!-- Boolean() with no arguments returns false in ActionScript 3.0. Boolean() returned undefined in ActionScript 2.0. -->
      <warn-boolean-constructor-with-no-args>false</warn-boolean-constructor-with-no-args>

      <!-- __resolve is no longer supported. -->
      <warn-changes-in-resolve>false</warn-changes-in-resolve>

      <!-- Class is sealed. It cannot have members added to it dynamically. -->
      <warn-class-is-sealed>true</warn-class-is-sealed>

      <!-- Constant not initialized. -->
      <warn-const-not-initialized>true</warn-const-not-initialized>

      <!-- Function used in new expression returns a value. Result will be what the -->
      <!-- function returns, rather than a new instance of that function.           -->
      <warn-constructor-returns-value>false</warn-constructor-returns-value>

      <!-- EventHandler was not added as a listener. -->
      <warn-deprecated-event-handler-error>false</warn-deprecated-event-handler-error>

      <!-- Unsupported ActionScript 2.0 function. -->
      <warn-deprecated-function-error>true</warn-deprecated-function-error>

      <!-- Unsupported ActionScript 2.0 property. -->
      <warn-deprecated-property-error>true</warn-deprecated-property-error>

      <!-- More than one argument by the same name. -->
      <warn-duplicate-argument-names>true</warn-duplicate-argument-names>

      <!-- Duplicate variable definition -->
      <warn-duplicate-variable-def>true</warn-duplicate-variable-def>

      <!-- ActionScript 3.0 iterates over an object's properties within a "for x in target" statement in random order. -->
      <warn-for-var-in-changes>false</warn-for-var-in-changes>

      <!-- Importing a package by the same name as the current class will hide that class identifier in this scope. -->
      <warn-import-hides-class>true</warn-import-hides-class>

      <!-- Use of the instanceof operator. -->
      <warn-instance-of-changes>true</warn-instance-of-changes>

      <!-- Internal error in compiler. -->
      <warn-internal-error>true</warn-internal-error>

      <!-- _level is no longer supported. For more information, see the flash.display package. -->
      <warn-level-not-supported>true</warn-level-not-supported>

      <!-- Missing namespace declaration (e.g. variable is not defined to be public, private, etc.). -->
      <warn-missing-namespace-decl>true</warn-missing-namespace-decl>

      <!-- Negative value will become a large positive value when assigned to a uint data type. -->
      <warn-negative-uint-literal>true</warn-negative-uint-literal>

      <!-- Missing constructor. -->
      <warn-no-constructor>false</warn-no-constructor>

      <!-- The super() statement was not called within the constructor. -->
      <warn-no-explicit-super-call-in-constructor>false</warn-no-explicit-super-call-in-constructor>

      <!-- Missing type declaration. -->
      <warn-no-type-decl>true</warn-no-type-decl>

      <!-- In ActionScript 3.0, white space is ignored and '' returns 0. Number() returns -->
      <!-- NaN in ActionScript 2.0 when the parameter is '' or contains white space.      -->
      <warn-number-from-string-changes>false</warn-number-from-string-changes>

      <!-- Change in scoping for the this keyword. Class methods extracted from an  -->
      <!-- instance of a class will always resolve this back to that instance. In   -->
      <!-- ActionScript 2.0 this is looked up dynamically based on where the method -->
      <!-- is invoked from.                                                         -->
      <warn-scoping-change-in-this>false</warn-scoping-change-in-this>

      <!-- Inefficient use of += on a TextField.-->
      <warn-slow-text-field-addition>true</warn-slow-text-field-addition>

      <!-- Possible missing parentheses. -->
      <warn-unlikely-function-value>true</warn-unlikely-function-value>

      <!-- Possible usage of the ActionScript 2.0 XML class. -->
      <warn-xml-class-has-changed>false</warn-xml-class-has-changed>

   </compiler>

   <!-- compute-digest: writes a digest to the catalog.xml of a library. Use this when the library will be used as a
                        cross-domain rsl.-->
   <!-- compute-digest usage:
   <compute-digest>boolean</compute-digest>
   -->

   <!-- remove-unused-rsls: remove RSLs that are not being used by the application-->
   <remove-unused-rsls>true</remove-unused-rsls>

   <!-- A list of runtime shared library URLs to be loaded before applications start. -->
   <!-- not set -->
   <!--
   <runtime-shared-libraries>
      <url>string</url>
      <url>string</url>
   </runtime-shared-libraries>
   -->

    <!-- runtime-shared-library-path: specifies a SWC or directory to link against and an RSL URL to load with optional failover URLs -->
      <!-- Framework SWC -->
    <runtime-shared-library-path>
        <path-element>libs/framework.swc</path-element>
        <rsl-url>http://fpdownload.adobe.com/pub/swz/flex/4.6.0.23201/framework_4.6.0.23201.swz</rsl-url>
        <policy-file-url>http://fpdownload.adobe.com/pub/swz/crossdomain.xml</policy-file-url>
        <rsl-url>framework_4.6.0.23201.swz</rsl-url>
        <policy-file-url></policy-file-url>
    </runtime-shared-library-path>

    <!-- TextLayout SWC -->
      <runtime-shared-library-path>
        <path-element>libs/textLayout.swc</path-element>
        <rsl-url>http://fpdownload.adobe.com/pub/swz/tlf/2.0.0.232/textLayout_2.0.0.232.swz</rsl-url>
        <policy-file-url>http://fpdownload.adobe.com/pub/swz/crossdomain.xml</policy-file-url>
        <rsl-url>textLayout_2.0.0.232.swz</rsl-url>
        <policy-file-url></policy-file-url>
    </runtime-shared-library-path>

      <!-- Spark SWC-->
    <runtime-shared-library-path>
        <path-element>libs/spark.swc</path-element>
        <rsl-url>http://fpdownload.adobe.com/pub/swz/flex/4.6.0.23201/spark_4.6.0.23201.swz</rsl-url>
        <policy-file-url>http://fpdownload.adobe.com/pub/swz/crossdomain.xml</policy-file-url>
        <rsl-url>spark_4.6.0.23201.swz</rsl-url>
        <policy-file-url></policy-file-url>
    </runtime-shared-library-path>

      <!-- Sparkskins SWC-->
    <runtime-shared-library-path>
        <path-element>libs/sparkskins.swc</path-element>
        <rsl-url>http://fpdownload.adobe.com/pub/swz/flex/4.6.0.23201/sparkskins_4.6.0.23201.swz</rsl-url>
        <policy-file-url>http://fpdownload.adobe.com/pub/swz/crossdomain.xml</policy-file-url>
        <rsl-url>sparkskins_4.6.0.23201.swz</rsl-url>
        <policy-file-url></policy-file-url>
    </runtime-shared-library-path>

    <!-- RPC SWC -->
    <runtime-shared-library-path>
        <path-element>libs/rpc.swc</path-element>
        <rsl-url>http://fpdownload.adobe.com/pub/swz/flex/4.6.0.23201/rpc_4.6.0.23201.swz</rsl-url>
        <policy-file-url>http://fpdownload.adobe.com/pub/swz/crossdomain.xml</policy-file-url>
        <rsl-url>rpc_4.6.0.23201.swz</rsl-url>
        <policy-file-url></policy-file-url>
    </runtime-shared-library-path>

      <!-- Charts SWC -->
    <runtime-shared-library-path>
        <path-element>libs/charts.swc</path-element>
        <rsl-url>http://fpdownload.adobe.com/pub/swz/flex/4.6.0.23201/charts_4.6.0.23201.swz</rsl-url>
        <policy-file-url>http://fpdownload.adobe.com/pub/swz/crossdomain.xml</policy-file-url>
        <rsl-url>charts_4.6.0.23201.swz</rsl-url>
        <policy-file-url></policy-file-url>
    </runtime-shared-library-path>

      <!-- Spark_dmv SWC -->
    <runtime-shared-library-path>
        <path-element>libs/spark_dmv.swc</path-element>
        <rsl-url>http://fpdownload.adobe.com/pub/swz/flex/4.6.0.23201/spark_dmv_4.6.0.23201.swz</rsl-url>
        <policy-file-url>http://fpdownload.adobe.com/pub/swz/crossdomain.xml</policy-file-url>
        <rsl-url>spark_dmv_4.6.0.23201.swz</rsl-url>
        <policy-file-url></policy-file-url>
    </runtime-shared-library-path>

      <!-- OSMF SWC -->
     <runtime-shared-library-path>
        <path-element>libs/osmf.swc</path-element>
        <rsl-url>http://fpdownload.adobe.com/pub/swz/flex/4.6.0.23201/osmf_1.0.0.16316.swz</rsl-url>
        <policy-file-url>http://fpdownload.adobe.com/pub/swz/crossdomain.xml</policy-file-url>
        <rsl-url>osmf_1.0.0.16316.swz</rsl-url>
        <policy-file-url></policy-file-url>
    </runtime-shared-library-path>

      <!-- MX SWC -->
    <runtime-shared-library-path>
        <path-element>libs/mx/mx.swc</path-element>
        <rsl-url>http://fpdownload.adobe.com/pub/swz/flex/4.6.0.23201/mx_4.6.0.23201.swz</rsl-url>
        <policy-file-url>http://fpdownload.adobe.com/pub/swz/crossdomain.xml</policy-file-url>
        <rsl-url>mx_4.6.0.23201.swz</rsl-url>
        <policy-file-url></policy-file-url>
    </runtime-shared-library-path>

      <!-- Advancedgrids SWC -->
    <runtime-shared-library-path>
        <path-element>libs/advancedgrids.swc</path-element>
        <rsl-url>http://fpdownload.adobe.com/pub/swz/flex/4.6.0.23201/advancedgrids_4.6.0.23201.swz</rsl-url>
        <policy-file-url>http://fpdownload.adobe.com/pub/swz/crossdomain.xml</policy-file-url>
        <rsl-url>advancedgrids_4.6.0.23201.swz</rsl-url>
        <policy-file-url></policy-file-url>
    </runtime-shared-library-path>

    <!-- static-link-runtime-shared-libraries: statically link the libraries specified by the -runtime-shared-libraries-path option.-->
    <static-link-runtime-shared-libraries>false</static-link-runtime-shared-libraries>

   <!-- target-player: specifies the version of the player the application is targeting.
                       Features requiring a later version will not be compiled into the application.
                       The minimum value supported is "9.0.0".-->
   <!-- target-player usage:
   <target-player>version</target-player>
   -->

   <!-- Enables SWFs to access the network. -->
   <use-network>true</use-network>

   <!-- Metadata added to SWFs via the SWF Metadata tag. -->
   <metadata>
      <title>Adobe Flex 4 Application</title>
      <description>http://www.adobe.com/products/flex</description>
      <publisher>unknown</publisher>
      <creator>unknown</creator>
      <language>EN</language>
   </metadata>

   <!-- licenses: specifies a list of product and serial number pairs. -->
   <!-- not set -->
   <!--
   <licenses>
      <license>
         <product>string</product>
         <serial-number>number</serial-number>
      </license>
   </licenses>
   -->

</flex-config>
```

Comment: This seems to have been resolved by using a different (newer, 4.13.0) SDK for Linux:
http://flex.apache.org/download-binaries.html